# Android Studio gettext not updating on click

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to make a login screen. When I get text from the textboxes on click however, the text doesn't update. Any ideas why?

My xml file for the first fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8E00A"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_first"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sc"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/login_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_first" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_box"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_box"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my first fragment java code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    EditText usernameT;
    EditText passwordT;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        usernameT = (EditText) fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.username_box);
        passwordT = (EditText) fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.password_box);
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.login_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = usernameT.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordT.getText().toString();
                Log.d("debug", username);
                Log.d("debug", password);
                if (username.equals("Na") && password.equals("Pa")) {
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                            .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
                } else {
                    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    myToast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }



}
```

As you can see I am printing to log the username and password everytime I click the button. However, even when I change the text, "Name" and "Password" are still being printed out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `hint`.

```
android:hint="Password"
```

and not

```
android:text="Password"
```

Edited:
Remove this line

```
View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
```

onCreateView should only contain the binding root layout

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }
```

Then you can access it on onViewCreated like

```
binding.login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         String username = binding.username_box.getText().toString();
     }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of it not getting the text though, instead of "Name" and "Password" it just returns an empty string now.

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer.

Comment: It says that it can't recognize the names of login_button and username_box

Comment: Can you check on your end? Maybe it is binding.loginButton in camelCase.

Comment: You're welcome, have a good day ahead.